# Extract files in rar archive without having some previous files

Tags: extract, rar, winrar

I have a big rar archive which is split into 700mb parts. I only have part 5 and 6 and there is a 40mb file in there that I wanna extract using Winrar. I know the whole file is stored in part 5 because when I open part 5, that file gets listed (and many other files). But I can't extract any of them, cause it asks for previous archive parts which I'm sure it really doesn't need.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: been ages and I never was that familiar with it but is it possible that when you open individual parts it lists the whole anyway?

Answer (score 2):

I think WinRAR has an option to "keep broken files" (under "Miscellaneous"). If you check that before extracting, you should be able to extract everything within that `.r05` file.

(Haven't checked, though, I'm on OS X)

Comment: Correct answer. There's a -kb option if you use the console rar version.

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar right now, and this doesn't seem to work, it still requires that all the previous files be present.